# Why returning "some View" doesn't work but using generic does?

Tags: generics, swiftui

Consider the following code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var content: () -> some View
  
  var body: some View {
    content()
      .padding()
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView() {
      VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
          .imageScale(.large)
          .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text("Hello, world!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler will complain about mismatching of types: "Cannot convert value of type 'VStack<TupleView<(some View, Text)>>' to closure result type 'some View'" [image: compiler errors]

However, if I change the signature of `ContentView` to use generic, it works.

```swift
struct ContentView<ChildView: View>: View {
  var content: () -> ChildView
  
  var body: some View {
    content()
      .padding()
  }
}
```

There are a couple of things I don't quite understand:

1. Why `VStack<TupleView<(some View, Text)` does not satisfy the `some View` requirement?
2. Are there any way we can make the `some View` work without resorting to generic? I'm not against using Generics at all, just want to use this to solidify my understanding of the `some` concept.

Comment: it might compile but it's wrong to store the closure instead of evaluating it in init and storing the View

Answer (score 0):

it might compile but it's wrong to store the closure instead of evaluating it in init and storing the View, e.g.

```
struct ContentView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a great tutorial about opaque types (the some keyword):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4WQFU7QrmM